# Is there a way to show "Example Value" and "Schema" next to each other in swagger/openAPI 3.0 documentation?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a swagger documentation written with swagger and openAPI 3.0. In the generated documentation of the request (and also response) it shows the "Example Value" and "Schema" as tabs of which you can choose either one or the other. Like this:

[image: Example Value and Schema Tabs]

Is there a way to show the "Example Value" and "Schema" next to each other instead of tabs such that you can see both immediately when you open the Request without clicking somewhere? Because otherwise the "Schema" is easily overseen and the developer may think that the "Example Value" is the only information they have for the request...

Comment: Not out-of-the-box, you'll need to fork & implement this yourself. Feel free to submit a feature request: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way as far as I know. But there are workarounds to be used once you implement swagger parsers using different programming languages.

Comment: how would a workaround in general look like? I am specifically using it on a nodeJS server with swagger-jsdoc 4.0.0, swagger-ui-express 4.1.4 and swagger-parser 9.0.1.

Comment: It's basically implementing each of the components using nodeJs. So you can add this "Example" field as an extra field.